# Planck's Law notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation, physical-constants

I have just picked up the book *Elementary Quantum Mechanics* by Peter Fong, and on the first page he writes Planck's law as $$u(\nu)d\nu=\frac{8\pi h \nu^3}{c^3}\frac{1}{e^{h\nu/kT}-1}d\nu$$ where $u(\nu)$ is the "energy per unit volume of the blackbody radiation in the frequency range from $\nu$ to $\nu + d\nu.$ This statement of the law differs from it statement on Wikipedia by a factor of $4\pi/c.$

My two questions are: First, what is the reason for this difference? I have checked the units for $h$ and $k$ and they seem to be the same as those used on Wikipedia, so I can't think of another reason for the difference in the constants. Second, what does $d\nu$ mean here, and how does $u(\nu)d\nu$ equal $B(\lambda,T)?$ (is the latter just the limit as $d\nu\to 0?$)

For background, I am a first-year Math Ph.D. student, however, I have mostly focused on algebra/discrete math, and my calculus is embarrassingly rusty. I did take AP Physics A and B in high school (my classes were algebra-based), but none in college, to my regret. I am mostly looking at this book because of personal curiosity, plus trying to refresh my calc skills while learning something new.

Comment: You're [conflating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Spectral_energy_density_form) energy density $u=4\pi B/c$ with [spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law) $B$. Also, a $d\nu$ factor should appear on both sides of the equation or neither, not just the left. (If Fong did it that way, it was a misprint.)

Comment: @J.G. Ahhh, that explains it! Thx! Mind if I ask, what does the dv mean here then?

Comment: @ConanG See edit.

Comment: @J.G. It does, that was just my mistype